# Styling all elements of Array with For-Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, for-loop

I have a div with a red border. I would like this border to disappear after lets say 3 seconds when the page is done loading. There are 3 images within this div and I'd like them to be opaque 0.1 after that same time. I tried doing this with a timer but it won't run. I was able to get the border part to work but when I try to do the images it doesn't run and Aptana says there an error where the for loop is.

```
function setPlaylist(){
    var playlist = document.getElementById('playlist');
    var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb').getElementByTagName('img');

    for( var i=0,i<thumbnails.length;i++)
    {
        thumbnails[i].style.opacity = ('0.1');
    }
    playlist.style.border = ('none');
    /*thumbnails.style.opacity = ('0.1');*/
}

function timerPL(){
    setTimeout(setPlaylist,3000);
}


window.addEventListener('load',timerPL,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('thumb').getElementByTagName('img');
//                 ^
//                  \_ It's plural. It'll return an array of elements
```

You need to iterate over them:

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    var thumb = thumbs[i];

    ...
}
```

If you don't care about older browsers, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('#playlist .thumb img');
```

Comment: So I have to write a var thumb1, var thumb2, etc for each element? I only have three images in there, seems like I might as well just get the elements by ID and do it that way without a loop.

Comment: @Batman: You need to put your original loop inside of the loop that I have in my question. Or just replace your `getElement...` calls with the `querySelectorAll` at the end of my answer and it should work.

Comment: If I store them all using querySelectorAll, would something like thumbnails.style.opacity = ('0.1'); be applied to all elements in that list? Sorry this is all new to me, trying to figure things out.

Comment: @Batman: Nope, you still have to iterate through the list with a `for` loop.